# How to center text in DropdownButton?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to make the `DropdownButton` hint, text and menu items appear in the center instead of left but `TextAlign.center` does not seem to be doing anything.

Image of Dropdown with the hint:

[image]

Image of Dropdown with the selected item as text:

[image]

Image of the Menu items when arrow is pressed:

[image]

My code:

```dart
return Theme(
  data: ThemeData(canvasColor: blackTrans2, brightness: Brightness.dark),
  child:Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/1.2,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: blackTrans,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
    ),   
    child:DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
      child: ButtonTheme(
        alignedDropdown: true,
        child: DropdownButton(
          value: _dateSelected,
          hint: AutoSizeText(NA_FLIGHT_PAGE_DROPDOWN, style: TextStyle(color: white,),textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
          isDense: false,
          onChanged: (String newValue){
            setState(() {
            _dateSelected = newValue;
            });
          },
          items: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document){
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: document.documentID,
              child: AutoSizeText(document.documentID, style: TextStyle(color: white,),textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    )
  )
);
```

Not sure if this affects anything but I'm using *[AutoSizeText](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text)* in order to resize my text dynamically.

**Update:** I managed to make the Menu items appear in the center by using `Center`, but the text and hint is still remains to the left tho even with `Center`... :

```dart
// Does not seem to change the hint or text position (when menu item selected)
hint: Center(child:AutoSizeText(NA_FLIGHT_PAGE_DROPDOWN, style: TextStyle(color: white,),textAlign: TextAlign.center,)),

// Changes the menu item to the center instead of left
child: Center(child:AutoSizeText(document.documentID, style: TextStyle(color: white,),textAlign: TextAlign.center,)),
```

Answer (score 28):

For those who are seeing option to change flutter class ***dropdown.dart***. You don't need to do that.
Do this:

1. set property ***isExpanded*** to ***true***
2. use ***Center*** widget with ***DropdownMenuItem*** class children.

IsExpanded will also take care of overflow.

```
DropdownButton(
     isExpanded: true,
     value: category_selected,
     items: categories.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((var value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value["name"],
          child: Center(
                 child: Text(
                        value["name"],
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ),
                 );
           }).toList(),
      ),
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple and straight answer is **Not Possible**. But there's always a way.

You have to go to the dropdown.dart provided with the flutter package.If you're using VSCode `Ctrl+Click` on the `DrpoDownMenuItem` class and change the following code.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: _kMenuItemHeight,
      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerStart,
      child: child,
    );
  }
```

Change the `alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerStart`  to  `alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center` and it should work :)

Comment: I have been messing with more library styles like this, but im wondering if this will all wipe out once they update a version or I do from my end? Any idea on how to persist such changes? :)

Answer (score 2):

> Yes you can do it like the following code sample.

```
Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))),
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5, left: 5),
              child: ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                  minWidth: double.infinity,
                ),
                child: Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                      child: DropdownButton(
                        iconSize: 0.0,
                        items: <DropdownMenuItem<int>>[
                          new DropdownMenuItem(
                            child: new Text(
                              'Optional Information',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                            ),
                          ),
                          new DropdownMenuItem(
                            child: new Text(
                              'Male',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                            ),
                          ),
                          new DropdownMenuItem(
                              child: new Text(
                            'Female',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                          )),
                        ],
                        onChanged: (V) {},
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

> Here i have used my color and decoration view for my porpose you can change it as per you requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to perfectly position the text in the dropdown at the center and still have the dropdown icon positioned at the right end of your container.

```
DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
  child: DropdownButton(
    value: dropdownvalue,
    items: items.map((String items) {
      return DropdownMenuItem(
          value: items,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(items),
          ),
      );
    }).toList(),
    onChanged: (String? newValue) {
      setState(() {
          dropdownvalue = newValue!;
      });
    },
    isExpanded: true,
  ),
),
```

So we simply add **isExpanded: true,** and add a **Center()** widget to the **Text(items)** in the **DropdownMenuItem()**.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `alignment` property in `DropdownMenuItem` class.

```dart
DropdownButton(
  //...
  isExpanded: true, // this will take all width available
)
```

If you want to change it's width wrap `DropdownButton` with `SizedBox` or `Padding`.

```dart
item: [
  DropdownMenuItem(
    //...
    alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
  ),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

in your DropdownButtonFormField or DropdownButton
add

```dart
isExpanded: true
```

thing like this

```dart
DropdownButtonFormField<String>(isExpanded: true)
```